# Sonar 6.7 SSO - How to trigger authentication?

Tags: sonarqube, single-sign-on

Hello there,

We've been using for some time a SSO plugin that we made to authenticate with an Identity provider (Crowd), since crowd-plugin does not support SSO.
Now, we have decided to upgrade Sonar to the new LTS 6.7. But our plugin was using HttpSession objects (created within servlet filters), which seemingly are not supported anymore as Sonar is now stateless.
We are not using OAuth2.

I've been searching for a bit but I am confused as to how I am supposed to achieve the authentication. The communication on Crowd side is successful, and I get the user details and a session token. My plugin has existing custom Authenticator, UserProvider and GroupsProvider that should work just fine.

But the authentication is never triggered on Sonar side. I can't find how to make sonar trigger the `doAuthenticate` method that my Authenticator override.

I can't use `BaseIdentityProvider` because the user is not supposed to make any action, he should connect automatically if he has the Crowd cookie or be redirected to our Crowd login page so he can connect ; and as my understanding of it goes `BaseIdentityProvider` just adds an option to connect with an external identity provider.

Do someone know how I can trigger an authentication from a servlet filter code ? Or do I have to start over and use a completely different way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to authenticate to SonarQube without having to click on any button is to use the HTTP header.

See the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authentication) for more details.

Comment: First, thank you for the quick answer. This being said, it's a bit embarassing because I managed it without using the 'new' HTTP header authentication. I actually extended a `BaseIdentityProvider` in which I throw `authenticate`  within the `init(Context)` method. Then I have my servlet filter throw a redirection toward `<sonar-base-url>/sessions/init/<identity-provider-key>`. It triggers the authentication and redirect toward sonar home without the user doing any input.

Comment: Interesting ! The BaseIdentityProvider has been provided in order to allow authentication by other way than OAuth2, but I never thought it could be used that way. Maybe you could create a open source plugin or provide some example somewhere, as it may be interesting for other users.

Comment: I might consider it when I have time and my plugin update is completed as a SSO for Crowd has been asked around a couple time so it would probably be useful for some people. Until then, you can check this out - it is where I have seen this method used : [reverse-proxy-auth-sonar-plugin](https://github.com/trajano/reverse-proxy-auth-sonar-plugin).

Comment: Thanks for sharing ! By the way, have you have a look of using directly HTTP header ? I'm asking, because having a plugin that is automatically log you to SonarQube is interesting if you need to do more than authentication, but otherwise I think it may be overkill as you'll be required to maintain it.

Comment: Actually, I did not. We were not using them before so it is just the easier way to to use filters. Atm our crowd is not sending us anything but the token, which we use to fetch manually the user details, so I tried naturally to resolve the issue within the sonar plugin and keep as much what was existing. I did not consider it would be a bigger effort to maintain it too.